# Modifying std::string internal buffer via the non-cont c++17 data() overload

Tags: c++, c++17, stdstring

I just saw that c++17 overloads a non-const data() method i.e. `CharT* data() noexcept;` and want to be sure that the behavior of calling it as follows is well defined:

```
std::string str(some_size,'0');
memcpy((void*)str.data(),source,some_size);
```

Comment: Oh god don't `(void*)str.data()` -- either it is a noop cast, or crazy dangerous; it could convert an integer to a void pointer, a pointer to const to a non-const.  If it is fed a pointer to non const ... it does zilch.  At the least `static_cast<void*>(ptr)` if you want to markup your casts to void so they sre obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is well-defined. This is the intended purpose of providing mutable access to the raw data.